# Pushing into array doesn't update the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created this fake conversation that loads last 20 messages and the next 20 or remaining messages when scrolled to the top of the page. For some reason the remaining messages are added successfully to `vm.messages` array (I can see that in the console) but do not become visible on the screen anytime after `loadMoreMessages` is called later.

I have absolutely no idea why this is  happening... I thought this might be because the view does not update correctly however when I created a function `vm.reply`, it has no problem adding one more message dynamically.

I have managed to load messaged 30 to 10 as expected but the first 10 do not appear on the screen after scrolling up.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($location, $anchorScroll, $document, $window) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.messagesInPart = 20; //number of messages in one part
  vm.messagesLoaded = 0;
  vm.conversation = [];
  vm.messages = [];
  
  $document.on('scroll', function() {
    if($window.scrollY === 0) {
       console.log('top of the page');
       loadMoreMessages();
    }
  });
  
  //fake conversation
  function getConversation() {
    for(var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
      vm.conversation.push({
        side: 'left',
        badgeClass: 'info',
        badgeIconClass: 'glyphicon-comment',
        content: "My own message " + i,
        userName: ''
      });
    }
    
    scrollToTheReply();
  }
  
  getConversation();
  
  function loadMoreMessages() {
     vm.messagesLeftToLoad = vm.conversation.length - vm.messagesLoaded;

     if(vm.messagesLeftToLoad > 0) {
        var iterationsUpTo = vm.messagesLeftToLoad >= vm.messagesInPart ? vm.messagesLeftToLoad - vm.messagesInPart : 0;
       
        console.log('iterationsUpTo = ', iterationsUpTo);

        for(var i = vm.messagesLeftToLoad - 1; i >= iterationsUpTo; i--) {
          vm.messages.unshift({
             side: vm.conversation[i].side,
             badgeClass: vm.conversation[i].badgeClass,
             badgeIconClass: vm.conversation[i].badgeIconClass,
             userName: vm.conversation[i].userName,
             content: vm.conversation[i].content
          });

          vm.messagesLoaded++;
       }
       
       console.log('vm.messages = ', vm.messages);
     }
  }
  
  loadMoreMessages();
  
  function scrollToTheReply() {
 $location.hash('reply');
 $anchorScroll();
  }

  vm.reply = function() {
     vm.messages.push({
       side: 'left',
       badgeClass: 'info',
       badgeIconClass: 'glyphicon-comment',
       userName: '',
       content: 'Reply msg'
     });
  }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rpocklin/angular-timeline/dist/angular-timeline-bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rpocklin/angular-timeline/dist/angular-timeline.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rpocklin/angular-timeline/dist/angular-timeline.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
       <div style="float: left;">
          <timeline>
             <timeline-event ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" side="{{message.side}}">
                <timeline-badge class="{{message.badgeClass}}">
                   <i class="glyphicon {{message.badgeIconClass}}"></i>
                </timeline-badge>
                <timeline-panel class="{{message.badgeClass}}">
                   <timeline-heading>
                      <h4>{{message.userName}}</h4>
                   </timeline-heading>
                   <p>{{message.content}}</p>
                </timeline-panel>
              </timeline-event>
            </timeline>
         </div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px;">
        <button type="button" id="reply" ng-click="vm.reply()">Reply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your snippet is not working

Comment: Fixed it. Should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not in a digest loop.

Trigger it with `$scope.$apply();`, `$scope.digest();` or `$timeout();` functions when calling `loadMoreMessages();` function.

Example:

```
$document.on('scroll', function() {
  if($window.scrollY === 0) {
     $timeout(function() {
      loadMoreMessages();
     });
  }
});
```

And don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller if you are going to use it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! By the way do you know how to detect user is still scrolling even though top of the page has been reached? My current code doesn't detect any scrolling after already at the top of the page.

Comment: If the user came to the end of the page, scrolling event won't be triggered. Basically he is not scrolling page anymore...

Comment: Yeah, I know :/ I am trying to detect that the user still scrolls up.